# Weird results when using the probability function from the discreteRV package

Tags: r, probability

```
library(discreteRV)
X <- RV(c(0, 9), c(1/2, 1/2))
Y <- RV(c(-3, 1), c(1/7, 6/7))

P1 <- P(X - Y > 0) # P1 = 0.57
P2 <- P( X - Y < 0 | X > 0) # P2 = 0
P3 <- P( X - Y < 0 | Y <= 0) # P3 = 3
P4 <- P(cos(pi * X * Y) < 1/2) # doesn't compile 
P5 <- P(X ** 2 + 3 * Y >= 3) # P5 = 0.9285
P6 <- P(X - Y < X ** 2 + 3 * Y) # P6 = 0
```

When I am using the built-in function P from the package [discreteRV](https://github.com/erichare/discreteRV), I get some really weird results. I've also tried a different approach and used the function sample to create a discrete random variable and the results seem ok

```
Xpmf <- c(1/2, 1/2)
X <- sample(c(0, 9), size = 10000, replace = TRUE, prob = Xpmf)
Ypmf <- c(1/7, 6/7)
Y <- sample(c(-3, 1), size = 10000, replace = TRUE, prob = Ypmf)
P1 <- mean(X - Y > 0) # P1 = 0.57
P2 <- mean( X - Y < 0 | X > 0) # P2 = 0.92
P3 <- mean( X - Y < 0 | Y <= 0) # P3 = 0.56 
P4 <- mean(cos(pi * X * Y) < 1/2) # P4 = 0.50
P5 <- mean(X ** 2 + 3 * Y >= 3) # P5 = 0.92
P6 <- mean(X - Y < X ** 2 + 3 * Y) # P6 = 0.92
```

Comment: What do you mean by "weird"?

Comment: For example, the third probability is equal to 3 and no probability should be greater than 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
Xpmf <- c(1/2, 1/2)
X <- sample(c(0, 9), size = 10000, replace = TRUE, prob = Xpmf)
Ypmf <- c(1/7, 6/7)
Y <- sample(c(-3, 1), size = 10000, replace = TRUE, prob = Ypmf)
P2 <- mean( X - Y < 0 | X > 0) # P2 = 0.92
```

you do *not* calculate an approximation of the conditional probability `P( X - Y < 0 | X > 0)`. The `|` in `mean( X - Y < 0 | X > 0)` is a logical OR, this is not a conditioning. It is easy to check that `X-Y` is never `<0` when `X>0`, so the correct value of `P2` is `0`.

The probability higher than `3` sounds like a bug. Or maybe you need to set the joint distribution with `jointRV`, I don't know whether `discreteRV` assumes independence by default.

---

## EDIT

The package does not assume independence by default:

```
> P((X == 0) %AND% (Y == 1)) # should be 1/2*6/7 if independence
[1] 0
```

So you have to use `jointRV`.

__

## EDIT

You can specify independence as follows:

```
XandY <- jointRV(
  outcomes = list(c(0,9), c(-3,1)), 
  probs = c(t(outer(c(1/2,1/2), c(1/7,6/7))))
)
X <- marginal(XandY, 1)
Y <- marginal(XandY, 2)
```

However that does not solve the issue:

```
P( X - Y < 0 | Y <= 0) # still 3
```

That's because `X-Y` and `Y` are not defined on the same sample space.

You can get this conditional probability as follows:

```
XminusY_and_Y <- joint(X-Y, Y)
XminusY <- marginal(XminusY_and_Y, 1)
Y <- marginal(XminusY_and_Y, 2)
P(XminusY < 0 | Y <= 0) # 0.3673469
```

Not highly convenient...

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the `P()` function cannot take the or operator (`|`) as you have put in. You could instead sum the probabilities, as here with P3 which equals 0.57116, very close to your simulation.

```
P(X - Y < 0) + P(Y <= 0)
```

Using more simulations I got 0.5712 so it appears summed probabilities this way works as you wanted.

```
xS <- sample(c(0,9), size = 1000000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.5, 0.5))
yS <- sample(c(-3,1), size = 1000000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(1/7, 6/7))
mean(xS - yS < 0 | yS <= 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

As pointed out by the first comment, the `|` in your second approach is a logical OR, so it does not calculate conditional probabilities. My previous answer was therefore misleading, and I think @StephaneLaurent answer provides all the clues.

I'll go through how the results from your second approach so you see what happens:

```
set.seed(1)
Xpmf <- c(1/2, 1/2)
X_sampled <- sample(c(0, 9), size = 10000, replace = TRUE, prob = Xpmf)
Ypmf <- c(1/7, 6/7)
Y_sampled <- sample(c(-3, 1), size = 10000, replace = TRUE, prob = Ypmf)
```

Let's look at those vectors:

```
head(X_sampled)
[1] 9 9 0 0 9 0
head(Y_sampled)
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Now you want to compute `mean(X_sampled - Y_sampled < 0 | X_sampled > 0)`. Let's decompose this:

```
head(X_sampled > 0)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSEn # this simply reflects 9, 9, 0, 0... 
head(X_sampled - Y_sampled < 0)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE # this reflects 9 - 1, 9 - 1, 0 - 1...
```

So `X_sampled - Y_sampled < 0 | X_sampled > 0` will look at all positions and determine whether `X_sampled` OR `X_sampled - Y_sampled < 0` is true at that position. The proportion of the resulting `TRUE`s is 0.9292.

Comment: The `|` in `mean(X_sampled - Y_sampled < 0 | X_sampled > 0)` is a logical OR, this is not a conditioning. One has `P2=0`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my error. Editing my response above. Recommend to accept @StéphaneLaurent's answer instead of mine